# Encryption conundrum

Tags: java, android, sql, security, encryption

I'm in the process of building an app that will send and receive data from a server.  Simple enough. In the event of severed connectivity, I have also begun to program the functionality of storing data until connectivity is gained.  This data would be stored locally on an SQLite database.

The data(not the table) is being encrypted, and I would store individual user salt/IV server-side.

Herein lies the crux of my problem.  If the user does not have connectivity, then he/she cannot connect to my server to retrieve their salt/IV, and if I store their individual keys on the device somewhere, then it's simple enough for anyone to take a peek at!

Is there a common practice that I could employ to ensure data security?  I find it hard to believe that there's no way to store data securely without a connection to the internet, but then again, I'm relatively new to this whole server communication business.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How secure are SQLite and SharedPreferences files on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608883/how-secure-are-sqlite-and-sharedpreferences-files-on-android)

Comment: That 'How secure' link is helpful but not a duplicate

Comment: Encrypt your data twice with the server knowing how the first local encryption was done? The first encryption would not have a salt of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to play the devil's advocate: who's to say that the server is not compromised and delivers a private key / salt/IV from an attacker? This could be done through a compromised access point for example or also through some Android malware that redirects host names to different IP addresses that replace your server.

It's not worth being worried about these potential problems. You are not responsible for keeping up the integrity of your users' devices. If I were you I'd just store the encryption key / credentials on the user device in the internal / private app storage.

If the user has a rooted or compromised system you are not to blame and I guess the user has much more to worry about.

On top of that you need to ask yourself the question, if your app in particular is worth for an attacker to study, address and exploit.

Comment: The app will deal with money and some rather sensitive information, so I could definitely see someone wanting to modify the information before the information is sent to the server.  I can't exactly go into detail, but just believe me when I say that it would cause some serious problems.

I never really thought about what you had to say bout security, though, and you're right.  It's not my responsibility to ensure that a user keeps their own device secure.  Thank you for your answer, friend.